# reset ng-grid structure after sorting and reloading data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

In ng-grid when I update the ngGridOptions "data:" variable with a call to a json service like api/customers.

```
    $scope.testData = function () {
        $scope.mySelections = []; // initialize mySelections
        $scope.myData = [{ NAME: "Test, Joe", ID: 1},"
                         { NAME: "Doe, JOhn", ID: 2},
                         { NAME: "Dow, JANE", ID: 3},
        ];
   }
```

Every thing is fine if I sort the fields ID, or Name.  But when I hit the button that is tied to the testData function it starts to change the structure of the ng-Grid control.  Is there a way to reset the structure so its fresh each time I hit my testData button?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle?  And did you mean to have a , after the ID: 3 item and a " at the end of the first ID: 1 item?

Comment: Are you wanting to wanting to remove any sorting, etc., that has been done to your grid each time you fetch the data set?

Comment: The first time I load the data its fine.  Its only after I adjust the sort order of a column, and then re-load the data on the SPA page does it start to degrade.   I wanted to refresh it so it wouldn't look like its changing its viewport heigh or grid view height.

Comment: I believe I found a problem.  If I add buttons to refill the grid right befor the last closing div to the ng-grid and re-populate it, ng-grid doesn't know what state its in so it changes the viewport sizing.